# Bug in Drop-Down?

Tags: support, reputation, activity-dropdown

Are the `0`'s a bug?

[image]

Yes, I tried Ctrl-F5, twice. No, it's not a cookie problem; it used to be fine. And no, I don't have any downvotes to cancel anything.

Comment: The real bug here is that the question titles are smushed right up against any two-digit scores... I've never noticed that on mine, even though I'm also using Chrome.

Comment: @Cody: That only happened when I made the browser window smaller; it's not normal on my system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You hit the reputation cap of 200 reputation per day. No more rep for you from answer's votes until 45 minutes.

Didn't you unlocked the badge for that maybe?

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOHHHHHHHHHHHH toootally forgot about that thing... thanks

Comment: And congratulations for a rep cap on SO. I wish I can get one too, but mod_rewrite questions does not reward enough :D

Comment: Lol, thanks :) hope you hit it soon too!